# Return array of Strings in API Platform

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I'm new to API Platform and am trying to clone an existing API. I have an entity `Tag` that has properties which are an id and a name. The default behaviour for `/api/tags` is to return an array of objects. Something like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "tag1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "tag2"
  }
]
```

What I actually want in the output is just a simple array of strings:

```
[
    "tag1",
    "tag2"
]
```

From the documentation, it sounds like I need to register a data transformer:

```
final class TagOutputTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function transform($data, string $to, array $context = [])
    {
        return $data->name;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function supportsTransformation($data, string $to, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return $data instanceof Tag;
    }
}
```

services.yaml:

```
services:
   
    'App\DataTransformer\TagOutputTransformer': ~
```

And annotate my entity:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get"={
 *             "method"="GET",
 *              "output"="string"
 *         }
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=TagRepository::class)
 */
```

The trouble is that `string` isn't a valid thing to put there in the annotation. I get `Class string does not exist`. If I remove the quotes, I get `Couldn't find constant string`.

Is this the right approach? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By specifying `"output"="string"`, you tell API Platform to *transform* your `Tag` resource to a `string` instance for output. `string`, however, is not a class and can not be instantiated (or transformed to).

What you want is to tell API Platform to transform `Tag` into a an object that [represents your desired data representation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/#specifying-an-input-or-an-output-data-representation).

For example, implement a custom `TagCollectionOutput` class (holding an array of `Tag` names) and add `"output"=TagCollectionOutput::class` to `Tag`. Then have `TagOutputTransformer` *transform* `$data` into a `TagCollectionOutput` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your data transformer may look like this:

```
final class TagOutputTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function transform($data, string $to, array $context = [])
        {
            return $data->name;
        }
    
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function supportsTransformation($data, string $to, array $context = []): bool
        {
            return $data instanceof Tag
                   && isset($context['collection_operation_name'])
                   && $context['collection_operation_name'] === 'get';
        }
    }
```

Specify the output class in the operation:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get"={
 *             "method"="GET",
 *              "output"=TagCollectionOutput::class
 *         }
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=TagRepository::class)
 */
```

And the output class contains just name:

```
class TagCollectionOutput
{
    public string $name;
}
```

That's enough to get an array of strings instead of objects.